# How to design FFC's/FPC's Even/Odd pattern in Altium

Tags: altium, fpc, ffc, flex

I want to design the even/odd pattern of FFC (flexible flat cable) in Altium. I don't know the exact term used to describe it, but the recommended drawing of this FFC from its target connector's manufacturer is here:

[image: FFC manufacturer's drawing]

Please note that I am asking for guidance in designing the yellow highlighted contacts. I have no idea how to make them in that shape.... Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-custom-pad-shapes-ad?version=19.1).

Answer (score 1):

Took @RohatKılıç's advice after finding nothing else helpful. The end result: [image: Here]